# What is the purpose of Outlook "Contacts" field?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

What is the purpose of **Contacts** field in Outlook?

It is supposed to be mail-related field and its value type is Text, but it is empty across all e-mail messages in my inbox.

[image]

Is it supposed to be set automatically by Outlook or Exchange Server in some scenarios?

Comment: If you look at this Outlook developer documentation (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/mailitem-object-outlook) then you'll notice that it suggests that there isn't a Contacts property for a mail item!

Comment: @Richard – but you can see it present in the *Field Chooser* > *All Mail fields*, right? I would like to know whether there is some application logic bound to it.

Comment: Sorry, yes I can see it and it's also empty for me too (Outlook 2013). It's very strange and I'm intrigued as to what the answer is - given that Microsoft don't appear to have bothered to document it.

Comment: @Richard – maybe it is possible that it belongs to different Outlook item type and is mistakenly classified as Mail field? (I can be wrong, just wondering...)  But I wasn't able to use Contact or Appointment item to put a value there.

Comment: If we work on the assumption that it's a property for a different item type then it might be either for a Task (https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Outlook-VBA/articles/taskitem-contactnames-property-outlook) or a Journal (https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Outlook-VBA/articles/journalitem-contactnames-property-outlook) item.

Answer (score 1):

After further research I found the answer. The field **Contacts** contains additional contacts attached to e-mail message:

[image]

Contacts placed in this field are transferred to the recipient, but only in shallow form (name and e-mail address), all other contact fields are lost. If the recipient already has the same contact in their contact list, the reference is restored based on transferred information.

---

The above **Properties** window can be open from the ribbon this way:

[image]